# Avoid looping in matlab when creating cells containing cell arrays

Tags: matlab, indexing, containers

I'm trying to create a map that has two-element cell arrays as values. Map expects that keys and values have the same number of elements. This code packs those cell arrays into cells in a loop, but I'm suspecting that it can be simplified somehow. Example code:

```
cells1={'foo1';'foo2';'foo3'};
cells2={'bar1';'bar2';'bar3'};
cells3={'baz1';'baz2';'baz3'};
values=cell(size(cells1));
for ii=1:size(cells1,1)
  values{ii}={{cells2{ii},cells3{ii}}};
end
keys=cells1;
containers.Map(keys,values);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use vector concatenation and `num2cell` with 2nd dimension argument (twice if you want to obtain identical result):

```
% your code
cells1={'foo1';'foo2';'foo3'};
cells2={'bar1';'bar2';'bar3'};
cells3={'baz1';'baz2';'baz3'};
values=cell(size(cells1));
for ii=1:size(cells1,1)
    values{ii}={{cells2{ii},cells3{ii}}};
end
% simplified
c = num2cell(num2cell([cells2,cells3],2),2);
% you can also do c = num2cell([cells2,cells3],2); which isn't identical but may be suficcient
isequal(c,values) % yes
```